# JMeter save results in csv file

Tags: csv, jmeter

I am using perfmon to get cpu and memory from server. I need to save all this info to csv file. The result is exactly what I need when I right click on for example cpu graph and click "Export to CSV...". The question is How I can do it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

When configuring the "jp@gc - PerfMon Metrics Collector" listener, provide a full-path filename (e.g., C:\metrics\perfmon_metrics.csv) in the "Write results to file/Read from file" section.

Results will be output to the the specified file. Open it, and you will find the corresponding metrics in the "**elapsed**" column.

Note: the memory metrics value is the actual metric value multiplied by 1000, while the CPU metrics value is the actual metric value multiplied by 100.

(I tried on JMeter 3.0 with jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1)

Answer (score 0):

In the "**jp@gc - PerfMon Metrics Collector**" plugin, provide Filepath & FileName in "**Write results to file/Read from file**" section.

**Note:** *Every time before running the test change the filename, in order to keep separate files for separate tests*.

Hope this will help.

Comment: No. File will contain no neded info. Actually there is no perf data. Even xml file doesn't contains this perf data.

Comment: then you will to write your on code, on top of "PerfMon Metrics Collector" Plugin.